# Angular replaces all / (backslash) with %5C

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a REST service on my PC. When I am sending Request url, browser(I am using chrome) converts all '/' with %5C. It works fine for some cases. But most of the cases url is changed.
error : for url : http://localhost:3028/controller/addFile?file=C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/Dhana/d/s.txt

```
GET http://localhost:3028/controller/addFile?file=C:%5CUsers%5CAcer%5CDesktop%5CDhana%5Cd%5Cs.txt 500
```

My component.ts code is:

```
filePath = 'http://localhost:3028/controller/addFile';
   addFile(file) : void{    
    this.params = new HttpParams();
    file = this.directory + '\\' + file;
    this.params = this.params.append('file', file);
    this.http.get(this.filePath, { params: this.params }).subscribe((data: any) => {
});
}
```

Comment: This is expected behavior. The values in query-string are always `url-encoded`

Comment: how to prevent this?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.

when it contains characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format. You have to Encode URL parameters and Decode when you are reading.

Comment: So is a backslash, or forward-slash, outside the ASCII character set?

Comment: Yes. Below are some samples. [ ----> %5B ,
\ ------> %5C ,
] ----->%5D ,
^ ----->%5E ,
_ ----->%5F         ,

Comment: shall I replace %5C with \ ?

Comment: @AndyG the back/forward slashes are not outside ASCII character set, but they cannot be used `as-is` in the query-string. So they need to be encoded. See the conversion here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: What should I do now. I want to send file path as parameter which contains \ (backslashes)?